# Set RenderFragment default content in code behind

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following code from an [article](https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/passing-placeholders-to-renderfragments/) that is placed inside a .razor file. How can the wig-pig code part be converted to a code behind .razor.cs file?

```
[Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> ItemTemplate { get; set; }

protected override void OnParametersSet()
  {
    if (ItemTemplate == null)
    {
      ItemTemplate = (item) => @:@{ 
      <li @key=item>@item.ToString()</li>}
      ;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to use RenderTreeBuilder syntax to do that in a `.cs` file - you can only mix markup and code in a razor file

Comment: I know all of that. Just need to know how can I add default content to the ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Mister Magoo's comment:

```
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<TItem> ItemTemplate { get; set; }
            = (TItem item) => (builder) =>
            {
                builder.OpenElement(0, "li");
                builder.SetKey(item);
                builder.AddContent(1, item.ToString());
                builder.CloseElement();
            };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I wanted ;)

Answer (score 9):

A bit opinionated but I think you are exaggerating the 'code-behind concept' a little.

An ItemTemplate will only see use in the markup section, I would opt for a (small) @code section:

```
@code {
  [Parameter] 
  public RenderFragment<TItem> ItemTemplate { get; set; } =
         item => @<li @key=item>@item.ToString()</li>;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as this is how it is done in practice and in all the MS examples.  Building a template in code behind is only suitable for the most simple template or a unique use case. Otherwise it is overly complex and difficult to read and modify later. +1